# How to get a valid Date as input from GUI

Tags: datetime, delphi

I have a school practical where users enter their date of birth in a `TEdit` on a `TForm`. The user will most likely enter the date according to their custom date settings, but I want to be able to convert any or at least most date formats to the one I have stored in a .mdb Access database. **How do I get an accurate and valid date from the GUI as user input?**

I know of the `decodedate(Date, year, month, day)` procedure, but what if the user enters the date differently than system settings or as is displayed in the `TDBGrid` connected to the .mdb database via an `ADOConnection` and `ADOTable`? Then the procedure will crash.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "specific TDateTime format". A `TDateTime` value has no format; it's a floating-point number representing a date and time. Your actual question, which by the way has nothing to do with databases, is "How to convert a string representing a date to a `TDateTime` value?" or, using other words, "How to parse a date string?" The answer is simple: "Write a date string parser". I can give you a suitable signature as a hint: `function ParseDate(const S: string): TDate`. Now you try to implement this!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I was providing context as to why I want the DateTime in a specific format. And what do you mean by: "TDateTime has no format"? When I debug the value changes depending on my system settings as `yyyy/mm/dd` or`yyyy-mm-dd`?

Would you mind explaining what the word "parse" means and how such a thing would work? Im in high school and still a novice. The education system sucks, so my apologies for the lack of knowledge.

Comment: The `TDateTime` is merely a number like 15623.25. When you debug, the IDE (Delphi) is actually using a function like `FormatDateTime` or `DateTimeToString` to create a string from this number. That's when the Windows locale settings are used. But the actual variable, stored in your computer's RAM, is 15623.25, and doesn't depend on the settings.

Comment: So your job is to create a function that takes a string like `'2021-08-09'` and then returns the `TDateTime` represented by the string. In this example: `44417.0`. You can do this by (1) extracting the Y, M, and D parts of the string to three local integer variables using the `Copy` and `StrToInt` (or `TryStrToInt`) functions and then (2) using `EncodeDate`. But if the input format can vary, you need to do this differently depending on the format. For instance, you can use `Pos` to see if the first delim is at pos 3 or at pos 5. Your function should raise if the input isn't valid.

Comment: It is impossible to do a general parser that accepts all date formats - there's too many that may conflict with each other, like dd/mm/yyyy (most European countries - delimiter may differ), mm/dd/yyyy (US format). The string 02/03/2012 - is that 02 March 2012 or 03 Feb 2012? You can't tell by only having the string by itself. You need to ask the user to specify the format (s)he enters the date in, like an additional drop-down where you select among the various formats mm/dd/yy, yy/mm/dd or dd/mm/yy (you can then extract one numer at a time, stopping at a non-digit character)...

Comment: ...until you have three values and then - according to the date format selected by the user - you can pass it into the EncodeDate routine.

Comment: @HeartWare's comments have been applicable since 12/10/11.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand  The whole problem concentrated in 8 characters!

Comment: "*We are not allowed to use the `TDateTimePicker` or calendar object in Delphi*" - why? That would e so much easier to hanfle this issue with. Unless this is for a homework/learning assignment, such a restrictive requirement is just dumb. OK, fine, it is what it is. I would suggest simply using 3 TEdits instead, 1 for month, 1 for day, 1 for year. Then you can combine them into any format you want, or convert them to integers individually, as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be a help to the user instead of a pain:

- Is "contains" meant literally, so the user can actually also enter dates with leading and/or trailing spaces? Such things occur, especially when copying texts from elsewhere. **Trimming** off such whitespaces is easy, so allow this. See [`trim()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.Trim)
- Avoid generic error messages but instead make them as **precise** as possible:

  - Wrong length? Tell what you expect and what you got instead, i.e.: "*Expected length: 10, but got 8 instead*."
  - No delimiter at expected position? Tell so, i.e.: "*Expected delimiter "/" as 5th letter, but got "3" instead.*"
  - Illegal month? Tell so, i.e: "*Expected "1" or "01" thru "12" as month, but got "23" instead.*"
- Try to **collect multiple error messages** at once, so the user can see all of his mistakes and fix them in one go, instead of being penalized again and again with just one message per take.
- Detect **patterns** and make them restrictive:

  - Pos #1 is `in ['0'.. '2']` and pos #2 thru #4 is `in ['0'.. '9']`? Looks like a **year** from which we can proceed:

    - Pos #5 is `in ['/', '-', '.']`?

      - Pos #6 is `'0'` and pos #7 is `in ['1'.. '9']`? Or pos #6 is `'1'` and pos #7 is `in ['0'.. '2']`?

  ...and so on. That way you can much better recognize which format has been chosen and you can give much more precise error messages. It will also lead to ambiguous input, such as `4/10/2016` from which you don't know if `4` is a day or a month.
- Check against **illegal dates**: which months cannot have a 31th day? For February 29th see [`IsLeapYear()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/IsLeapYear_(Delphi))
- **Display** the date according to what you recognized - this helps you and your user to make sure the recognition was correct. Ideally you have your three Integers of year, month and date and then convert them to text again, along with delimiters - the outcome should be in general the input you had to deal with.
- **[Regular expressions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Regular_Expressions)** are great in recognizing patterns and then accessing the found parts. However, it's a topic on its own and should only be used when known on its own. A regex for the format I used in this example would be `/([0-2][0-9]{3})[/.-](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[/.-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/` where you can easily access `$1` as year, `$2` as one or two digit month and `$3` as one or two digit day. You "only" have to check against illegal dates.

Answer (score 0):

As @AndreasReijbrand pointed out, a `TDateTimePicker` would be the correct method to receive a date as user input on a GUI. The `TDateTimePicker` does all the validation work for you. After much debate, we were eventually allowed to use it. I post this new answer with some important insights to the TDateTimePicker component:

1. The `TDateTimePicker` automatically changes to the local set date format of the pc. So validation of that is unnecessary.
2. Conversion of date display format (`yyyy/mm/dd` or `yyyy-mm-dd`) from the `.mdb` Access database to the `TDateTimePicker` and vice versa is unnecessary. This is also done automatically. (Starting to see why there was so much criticism for the original lack of use of this component.)
3. The `DateTimePicker` does not allow negative values or non-sensical values such as (`0030/09/08` or `2003/89/89`).

Comment: Welcome to the internet - it works thru links: [Microsoft docs for those controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/date-and-time-picker-controls), then [Embarcadero's component](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker) and [all Qs on SO for that (even has its own tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetimepicker+delphi).